# The difference between the stars in chat, why all the confusion anyhow?

Tags: support, chat, chat-stars

Looking in a chat room at the panel on the right with all the starred messages, I noticed 3 kinds of stars.

1. ☆ (star outlined)
2. ★ (star filled)
3. [image: gold star image] (gold star filled)

The gold star is easy enough for me, it means, that **I** starred it. What are the other 2 for, what do they mean? (if filled or if outlined)

[image]

Comment: Black means you haven't starred it but others have. White means that the chat room owners or a mod have pinned that message to the star board.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing care to make it an answer, and possibly provide sources as well?

Comment: Not really, I think Catija's answer covers it quite well. I'd prefer to just upvote their answer.

Comment: I am disappointed that you don't like stickers, WELZ. :P

Comment: I am disappointed that you don't like project links, Catija :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The open star is a pin.**

A moderator or room owner can pin messages as important and they'll stay there at the top of the list. These pinned messages stick around for up to 14 days (or until the pin is removed).

**Yellow stars are your stars.**

These are messages that you have starred yourself.

**Black stars are those made by others**

You haven't starred this message but someone else has.

There's actually a fourth star.

**The outlined gold star**

[image: Outlined gold star]

If you also star a pinned message, you'll see a gold filled pin star. It looks the same whether you've pinned it or just starred it after someone else pinned it. As "proof" of this, the outlined gold star above is one that I've pinned and the one in the image below is one that I've just starred myself.

So, using the same chat room you're in:

[image: All star types at once]

As far as I know, there's not really a clear explanation of the differences but there is the [Chat FAQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq), which gives some guidance (go to the main FAQ page and search for "star").

It explains that both stars and pins are possible but not how they look. It does mention that pins last for 14 days.

> Starred messages appear in the room sidebar, ordered by number of stars and last time of starring. (Room owners can also pin messages, which permanently affixes them to the top of the room sidebar for up to 14 days.) The room sidebar is intended to be a collaboratively created mini-timeline of interesting room events for people who don't have time to read the entire chat transcript for that particular room.

---

Users may star up to 20 messages per day and Room Owners may additionally pin up to 20 messages per day - per room. Moderators have no limits on the number of stars or pins they may use (on the servers they're moderators on).

Comment: Aha, it was for this why you made us do the [experiment](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/41120086#41120086).  :p

Comment: It was invaluable :D And amusing.